# Best way to create a table of matches with an existing DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matching

I'm looking for the best possible way to use an existing pandas DataFrame to create a table of matches. For each two rows (a pair), it should append the *next* entry to the first item, and for the second item, it should append the *previous* entry.

Input:

```
I Name Var  ...
0 A    Var1 ...
1 B    Var2 ...
2 C    Var3 ...
3 D    Var4 ...
4 E    Var5 ...
5 F    Var6 ...
```

**Desired Output (Pairs)**:

```
I Name_1 Var_1 ..._1 Name_2 Var_2 ..._2
0 A      Var1  ...   B      Var2  ...
1 B      Var2  ...   A      Var1  ...
2 C      Var3  ...   D      Var4  ...
3 D      Var4  ...   C      Var3  ...
4 E      Var5  ...   F      Var6  ...
5 F      Var6  ...   E      Var5  ...
```

I want to do so, in order to inform each entry about the respective match in a database.

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try something new with `argsort`:

```
i = np.argsort(df.index[::-1] // 2)[::-1]
df.join(df.iloc[i].reset_index(drop=True), lsuffix='_1', rsuffix='_2')
```

---

```
  Name_1 Var_1 Name_2 Var_2
0      A  Var1      B  Var2
1      B  Var2      A  Var1
2      C  Var3      D  Var4
3      D  Var4      C  Var3
4      E  Var5      F  Var6
5      F  Var6      E  Var5
```

Comment: Did you try it with an example df? I just tied, and it somehow did not change anything :/ It's just a copy of the first that is added.

Comment: @Christopher lets discuss [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228691/ds5)

Answer (score 2):

You can try reshaping it and reverting the values along axis=1, then `pd.concat` with `add_suffix`:

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=df.to_numpy().reshape(df.shape[0]//2, 2, df.shape[1])[:, ::-1, :].reshape(df.shape),
    columns=df.columns
)

>>> pd.concat([df.add_suffix('_1'), df2.add_suffix('_2')], axis=1)

  Name_1 Var_1 ..._1 Name_2 Var_2 ..._2
0      A  Var1   ...      B  Var2   ...
1      B  Var2   ...      A  Var1   ...
2      C  Var3   ...      D  Var4   ...
3      D  Var4   ...      C  Var3   ...
4      E  Var5   ...      F  Var6   ...
5      F  Var6   ...      E  Var5   ...
```

Alternatively, instead of working with the entire `df`, you can just `reshape` the `index` and `reindex` with it:

```
>>> new_index = df.index.to_numpy().reshape(df.shape[0]//2, 2)[:, ::-1].reshape(-1,)
>>> pd.concat([
        df.add_suffix('_1'),
        df.reindex(new_index).add_suffix('_2').reset_index(drop=True)
        ], axis=1
    )

  Name_1 Var_1 ..._1 Name_2 Var_2 ..._2
0      A  Var1   ...      B  Var2   ...
1      B  Var2   ...      A  Var1   ...
2      C  Var3   ...      D  Var4   ...
3      D  Var4   ...      C  Var3   ...
4      E  Var5   ...      F  Var6   ...
5      F  Var6   ...      E  Var5   ...
```

Comment: Very neat use of `reshape`.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can get to your desired outcome quite simply using `shift` and some simple manipulation:

```
# Shift both variables by 1 
df[['Name_2','Var_2']] = df[['Name','Var']].shift(-1,axis=0)

# Replace odd indexed rows of the last 2 columns, with even indexed rows of the first 2 columns
df.iloc[1::2,-2:] = df.iloc[::2,:2] 

# Rename
df.rename(columns={'Name':'Name_1','Var':'Var_1'},inplace=True)

df
Out[69]: 
  Name_1 Var_1 Name_2 Var_2
0      A  Var1      B  Var2
1      B  Var2      A  Var1
2      C  Var3      D  Var4
3      D  Var4      C  Var3
4      E  Var5      F  Var6
5      F  Var6      E  Var5
```

This will get you the pairs. Not sure this is what you need, but thought i'd post it.

Comment: Looks clean. I currently think whether the first method works better practically, just because I have about 10 variables per row. Is there another way?

Comment: I agree with you that the other method works practically better, this is a bit of an ad-hoc solution. So if you have more variables, I guess what will change will be the ```shift``` part and the renaming part. Replacing odd indexed rows with even indexed rows I guess will stay the same. Is there a chance you can post a bigger sample of your data to test it?